# native HTTP / HTTPS traffic observer for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, http

I'm using Ubuntu natively, and have a Windows VM running most of the time also, so at the moment I am routing my Ubuntu traffic through my Windows VM and using Fiddler that way, but is there a native alternative?

Fiddler shows you the details of every HTTP Request/Response sent by your computer. Unencrypted initially, but you can install an HTTPS certificate locally to effectively MITM yourself and see encrypted traffic also. For each request you see the URL, Headers and Body (if available) of both the request and response.

Comment: See http://alternativeto.net/software/fiddler/?platform=linux

Comment: Could you describe what Fiddler does? Currently only people who already know the tool can properly answer the question. If you would describe what it does, a person who knows a proper tool (but not fiddler) could answer this.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs It shows you the details of every HTTP Request/Response sent by your computer. Unencrypted initially, but you can install an HTTPS certificate locally to effectively MITM yourself and see encrypted traffic also. For each request you see the URL, Headers and Body (if available) of both the request and response. Make sense?

Comment: @JMK Yes. Better, thanks. Are you looking for gratis / open-source software or is paying for it okay?

Comment: I guess this is Software Recommendations SE so all are good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the Mono Build of Fiddler from [here](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono) with it's various dependencies.  Alternatively [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483/can-anybody-recommend-an-http-debugging-proxy) suggests:

- WebScarab: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_Project
- Burp http://portswigger.net